# How to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally

Tags: java, json, jackson

Default jackon behaviour seems to use both properties (getters and setters) and fields to serialize and deserialize to json.

I would like to use the fields as the canonical source of serialization config and thus don't want jackson to look at properties at all.

I can do this on an individual class basis with the annotation:

```
 @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

But I don't want to have to put this on every single class...

Is it possible to configure this globally? Like add some to the Object Mapper?

Comment: Tim gave a good answer. Another possibility is that if you have a common base class, you can put class annotations to that one; annotations are inherited by Jackson.

Comment: I think I tried that, but it seems you have to tell the sub classes to use what the base case defines...

Comment: No, unless sub-class overrides class annotation, parent's annotations are visible as if they were part of sub-class definition (if not, this would be a bug). This is not necessarily how JDK deals with annotations, but Jackson implements full inheritance for annotations (even for method annotations).

Comment: Beware of the `INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS` flag. It forces the visibility of setters if there is a visible getter or field.

Comment: [And others](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.java).

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can configure individual ObjectMappers like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

If you want it set globally, I usually access a configured mapper through a wrapper class.

Comment: Good, although I think you may need to also set the checker (withXxx() methods usually create a new object). So something like 'mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getVisibilityChecker().with...);'

Comment: @StaxMan good call on setVisibilityChecker, I edited the answer to reflect.

Comment: `withGetterVisibility` doesn't cover `is*` methods, but there's `withIsGetterVisibility` for them.

Comment: ```setVisibilityChecker```is deprecated. Use ```setVisibility``` instead.

Comment: This is just what I needed!  This configuration allowed me to use a Mixin to easily convert Hibernate entities to DTOs.  By default the ObjectMapper serializes everything and a Mixin would have to specify which properties to ignore (i.e. a subtraction instead of an intersection).

Answer (score 184):

In Jackson 2.0 and later you can simply use:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;   

...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

to turn off autodetection.

Comment: Hi guys, 

I am using Jackson 1.9.0 jar. 
I am getting additional json property, while serializing object to json string.
I need to get the json string, which contains only mentioned variables with @JsonProperty.

Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: You can start with class annotation mentioned in OP question:
`@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)`
Next, you have to annotate each property you want to include with `@JsonProperty`

Comment: Thanks! Before, I've found many code examples where JsonMethod was referenced instead of PropertyAccessor. If you search for JsonMethod, you rarely get links to PropertyAccessor then... What is the best way to find replacement class names in successor artifacts? Can be tough and nasty, no?

Answer (score 47):

**Specifically for `boolean is*()` getters:**

I've spend a lot of time on why neither below

```
  @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

nor this

```
  setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
  setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
  setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

worked for my Boolean Getter/Setter.

Solution is simple:

```
  @JsonAutoDetect(isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, ...          
  setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
```

UPDATE: spring-boot allowed configure it:

```
jackson:
  visibility.field: any
  visibility.getter: none
  visibility.setter: none
  visibility.is-getter: none
```

See [Common application properties # JACKSON](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Could you elaborate how simple solution should be applied to bean class?

Comment: Thank you. That isGetter saved the day for me.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and is rather misleading.

Answer (score 18):

for jackson 1.9.10 I use

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

to turn of auto dedection.

Comment: wonder if there's any difference between doing this and disabling the "auto detects".

Answer (score 10):

How about this: I used it with a mixin

non-compliant object

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Telemetry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long pk;
    private String id;
    private String organizationId;
    private String baseType;
    private String name;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lon;
    private Instant updateTimestamp;
}
```

Mixin:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = ANY, getterVisibility = NONE, setterVisibility = NONE)
public static class TelemetryMixin {}
```

Usage:

```
    ObjectMapper om = objectMapper.addMixIn(Telemetry.class, TelemetryMixin.class);
    Telemetry[] telemetries = om.readValue(someJson, Telemetry[].class);
```

There is nothing that says you couldn't foreach any number of classes and apply the same mixin.

If you're not familiar with mixins, they are conceptually simply: The structure of the mixin is *super imposed* on the target class (according to jackson, not as far as the JVM is concerned).

Answer (score 7):

If you use Spring Boot, you can configure Jackson **globally** as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

@Configuration
public class JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a way to do this globally without worrying about the configuration of your `ObjectMapper`, you can create your own annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonAutoDetect(
        getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE
)
public @interface JsonExplicit {
}
```

Now you just have to annotate your classes with `@JsonExplicit` and you're good to go!

Also make sure to edit the above call to `@JsonAutoDetect` to make sure you have the values set to what works with your program.

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408807 for helping me find out about `@JacksonAnnotationsInside`

Answer (score 4):

`@since 2.10` version we can use [JsonMapper.Builder](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/json/JsonMapper.Builder.html) and accepted answer could look like:

```
JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .visibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    .visibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .visibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .visibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .visibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
.build();
```

Comment: +1 – The absolute cleanest way to configure your JsonMapper. Period. May be worth including `IS_GETTER` here for completeness – although it's not what the OP *explicitly* asked for, they implicitly want it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's very tricky in Kotlin with data classes and is* methods. For example for class:

```
data class SomeClass(val foo: String, val bar: String, val isSomething: Boolean):Serializable { fun isEmpty() = foo.isEmpty() }
```

I'm getting json like: `{"bar"="bar", "empty"=false, "foo"="foo", "isSomething"=true}`
And after setting: `setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)`
the json is: `{"bar"="bar", "foo"="foo"}`

The only way I found to have `isSomething` and do not have `empty` is adding the `@JsonIgnore` or `@JvmSynthetic` annotation on `isEmpty()`

Moreover the fun fact is that adding method like `isFoo(): Boolean` serializes foo only once, as a String.