# How do I configure a Jackson ObjectMapper to show only whitelist properties?

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do I configure an ObjectMapper to map only properties annotated with JsonProperty?  (does not have to be this particular annotation, but this seemed the most sensible)

I am looking for something that works like Gson's @Expose annotation and GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create() serializer [Example](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html).

```
class Foo {
    public String secret;

    @JsonProperty
    public String biz;
}

class FooTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        // configure the mapper

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.secret = "secret";
        foo.biz = "bizzzz";
        System.out.println(m.writeValueAsString(foo));
        // I want {"biz": "bizzzz"}

        m.readValue("{\"secret\": \"hack\", \"biz\": \"settable\"}", Foo.class);
        // I want this to throw an exception like secret does not exist
    }
}
```

Thanks, Ransom

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally)

Answer (score 3):

From [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally) except I do not want fields to be used either.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```