# Duplicate json property when converting java object to json string using jackson

Tags: java, json, properties, duplicates, jackson

I have Pojo object, with getAsJson function to return Json string for this object.
I use JsonProperty to define json properties in this object.
Use writeValueAsString of ObjectMapper to write json string for this object.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class LogLikeArticleDetail extends BaseObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2018373118257019033L;
    @JsonProperty("LikeArticleGUId")
    private String likeArticleGUId;
    @JsonProperty("UserId")
    private String userID;
    @JsonProperty("UserName")
    private String userName;
    @JsonProperty("IP") 
    private String ip;
    @JsonProperty("OS") 
    private String os;
    @JsonProperty("UserAgent") 
    private String userAgent;
    @JsonProperty("WebsiteCode") 
    private String websiteCode;
    @JsonProperty("ArticleId") 
    private String articleID;
    @JsonProperty("ATitle") 
    private String aTitle;
    @JsonProperty("CateAlias") 
    private String cateAlias;
    @JsonProperty("LikeStatus") 
    private String likeStatus;
    @JsonProperty("TimeStamp") 
    private Date timeStamp;
        //get, set....
        //....
        @JsonIgnore
    public String getAsJSON() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException,    IOException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(this) ; 
    }
}
```

Now, i get result

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
        LogLikeArticleDetail logLikeArticle = new LogLikeArticleDetail("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","what thing \"nothing\" show","10","11",calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(logLikeArticle.getAsJSON());
    }
```

But the result's duplicated properties:

```
{"LikeArticleGUId":"1","UserId":"2","UserName":"3","IP":"4","OS":"5","UserAgent":"6","WebsiteCode":"7","ArticleId":"8","ATitle":"what thing \"nothing\" show","CateAlias":"10","LikeStatus":"11","TimeStamp":1352256727062,"_likeArticleGUId":"1","websiteCode":"7","likeStatus":"11","userID":"2","userName":"3","ip":"4","os":"5","userAgent":"6","articleID":"8","aTitle":"what thing \"nothing\" show","cateAlias":"10","timeStamp":1352256727062}
```

Show me what's occur in this problem ?

Comment: I think this might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So i do follow:
[how to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally)

I add

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

before

```
public class LogLikeArticleDetail extends BaseObject
```

and the result that i want.

So can another solve that in getAsJson() function like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
return mapper.writeValueAsString(this) ;
```

Thanks for @Sean Carpenter 's question and @kmb385 answer in link above.

Comment: This work like a charm, but is deprecated, correct answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108530/976259

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this per POJO using annotations. Add this string to the top of your class you'd like no auto detection on:

> @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,
>   getterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
>   setterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
>   creatorVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)

For example:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        setterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, creatorVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
class Play {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name; 

    @JsonProperty("NickName")
    private String nickName; 

    public Play(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }
}
```

This will return the properties I've defined and not auto-detect the field names and add them to my returned JSON result.

Answer (score 6):

We can also use the @JsonProperty("Name") annotation directly on the getters to avoid duplication.

Comment: This is possibly the simplest solution. When the object has to be deserialized by the consumer, it's obviously the getter that is called. Thank you @Gogol

Answer (score 4):

It is actually not an issue. So, over here what happened was Jackson library was unable to match those fields automatically (there is no assumption of case unification), so you end up with twice the properties you expect.

The simple fix for this issue is to just add annotations to either getters/setters (either is fine.)

```
@JsonProperty("UserName")
public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
}
```

This issue was also raised in Jackson Github repo. You can find the answer in the following link.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1609