# How to create an annotation that is a group of Jackson annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

A year or so I read an article that explained how I could create an annotation that basically is a container for other annotations. This way if I always use the same 5 annotations in a specific use-case I create an annotation that contains them and use that instead.

Unfortunately, I can't find the article anymore and would really like to do that right now for my jackson configuration.

Since I can't find any information on that on my own I'm beginning to question my memory. Is this possible or I am  just wrong?

**EDIT**

What i want is something like:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize(using=MySerializerThatIsUsedEverywhere.class
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyCustomXmlAdapter.class)
@SomeOtherEvaluatedByTheSerializer
public @interface SerializerUseCase01 {
    public String a();
    public int b();
)
```

my scenario is that i have a bunch of serialization use cases that can be handled by the same serializer with different configs. To make everything easier to use and more transparent i want to wrap the jackson config and the serializer config into one annotation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For Jackson, this can be done with `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` meta-annotation. See [this article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_466.html) for more, but code snippet from there is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // IMPORTANT
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name" }) 
public @interface MyStdAnnotations
```

and from thereon you can use this type for your own classes like so:

```
@MyStdAnnotations
public class MyBean {
   public String name, id;
}
```

Comment: Does this work only thanks to `@JacksonAnnotationsInside`? Is there something like groovy's meta-annotations (`groovy.transform.AnnotationCollector`)? In Groovy documentation it says that `INFO: Meta-annotations are a Groovy feature only. There is no chance for you to annotate a Java class with a meta-annotation and hope it will do the same as in Groovy. Likewise, you cannot write a meta-annotation in Java: both the meta-annotation definition and usage have to be Groovy code.`, but since this works then there is some possiblity.

Comment: Unless Groovy annotations are handled by some other processor to expand them, no, Jackson does not recognize them. However, if it would behave similar to `JacksonAnnotationsInside`, it is actually possible to define "aliases" by overriding a method in `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, which is responsible for detecting annotation bundles.

Comment: Thanks! The key is `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` otherwise jackson ignores any jackson-specific annotations added.  I tried `@Inherited` and it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

There are some examples [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/toddfast/entry/creating_nested_complex_java_annotations) on how to make various combinations of annotations containing other annotations. Is this what you're looking for?

Example from the source:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SimpleAnnotation {
    public String a();
    public int b();
)

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ReallyComplexAnnotation {
    public SimpleAnnotation[] value();
)
```

Used like this:

```
@ReallyComplexAnnotation(
    { @SimpleAnnotation(a="...", b=3), @SimpleAnnotation(a="...", b=4) }
)
```

Comment: Hmm. So you want `SerializerUseCase01` to be something akin to an alias for a bunch of other (hidden as an implementation detail) interfaces, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. But I'm not sure anymore that is possible as none of the annotations i want to "hide" is marked with `@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,...}`.

Comment: I've never tried to do something like that, but looking for it I've come across what looks like it [here](http://cyrille.martraire.com/2010/07/patterns-for-using-annotations/) (scroll down to "Meta-inheritance" - the "PayPal" example looks particularly like this). By the looks of that any annotations on your annotation will be "added" to your annotation. Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but worth a go.