# How to combine annotations for hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

Assuming that (using [JPA](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_JPA%3F)) I have an entity with an id:

```
...
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "EVENT_GEN",
                table = "SEQUENCES",
                pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
                valueColumnName = "SEQ_NUMBER",
                pkColumnValue = "ID_SEQUENCE",
                allocationSize=1)
private Long id;
...
```

how can I declare a custom annotation so the above id mapping will be :

```
@CustomIdAnnotation
private Long id
```

May be something like this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408807/2114786).

Comment: JPA 2.2 will support "meta-annotations", and DataNucleus JPA already provides that  http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/annotations.html#meta_annotations  No idea if Hibernate supports that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Neil Stockton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380338/neil-stockton) [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239955/how-to-combine-annotations-for-hibernate-mapping/45492792#comment77446813_45239955), the meta annotation will probably be a [part](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/43) of next JPA version 2.2.

And for now, with JPA 2.1, I can use [@Embeddable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) class for both id ([@EmbeddedId](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html)) and non-id field ([@Embedded](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html))

Just to note that for @Embeddable, I can use a generic class, so it will be useful for any type + I can easily override my column attributes:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor // Lombok library
public class EmbeddableGeneric<T> {
    @Column 
    // other annotations
    T myField;
    
    ...
}
```

and in my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor // You know now what's this!
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "myField", column = @Column(name = "STRING_FIELD"))
    private EmbeddableGeneric<String> myString;

...
}
```

Let's wait for JPA 2.2 to overcome this verbosity.

Comment: The link to the GitHub issue link here is outdated. Java EE has been deprecated, and the Eclipse Foundation has taken on the task of furthering its projects and specifications as part of [EE4J](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j). Here's the new location to track progress on this issue: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

**Theoretically** it should be something like this:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface CustomIdAnnotation {

    TableGenerator generator() default @TableGenerator(name = "EVENT_GEN", 
            table = "SEQUENCES", 
            pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", 
            valueColumnName = "SEQ_NUMBER", 
            pkColumnValue = "ID_SEQUENCE", 
            allocationSize = 1);

    Id id();
}
```

However, I think that this will not work because the persistence provider (Hibernate, EclipseLink,etc..) processes annotations of package `javax.persistence.*` + provider specific annotations directly in your entity class. So this may work if you plan to write your own persistence provider. ([implementing JSR-000338 JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html))

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to put your id inside your custom annotation, the idea is to group my verbose and duplicated JPA annotations in a signle one.