# Sprint Date Rest successful, but no data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Entity

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_NOTE")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Note implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Date date;
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String content;
    private String title;
    private String weather;
}
```

Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "note", path = "note")
public interface NoteRepository extends AbstractRepository<Note, Long>
{

}
```

GET http://localhost:8080/note/2

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/note/2"
        }
    }
}
```

No entity field data, why?

**EIDT**

After I add standard setter/getter, everything is ok now.

```
public Long getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date)
{
    this.date = date;
}

public String getContent()
{
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content)
{
    this.content = content;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}

public String getWeather()
{
    return weather;
}

public void setWeather(String weather)
{
    this.weather = weather;
}
```

Is this cause by jackson mapper ? How can I use fluent API with this ?Why not just use reflection to generate JSON ?

**EDIT**

What I need is this configuration

```
@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class ShoweaRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
{
    @Override
    protected void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    }
}
```

Caused by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745)

Comment: If you remove `@Accessors`, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Accessors` is probably stepping over the `@Data` annotation, and with `fluent = true` it generates getters with the same name as the field, like `id()` and `date()` ([@Accessor documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors.html)). That's why Spring doesn't see any of the fields.

I think you can safely remove both `@Accessors` and `@Access`, since `@Access`'s takes the default value from `id` (if you annotated the field, it will be `FIELD`, if you annotated the getter, it will be `PROPERTY`).

Comment: Yes, it works, I just add setter/getter not change the fluent accessor.updated the question, but why ?