# Can Jackson converte a POGO to JSON in spring without @JSONProperty?

Tags: spring-mvc, groovy, jackson

How can jackson `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` converte a pogo into a json without `@JSONProperty` ON every Property?

I use groovy in spring boot project and no java code, I hava a domain model named `FileInfo.groovy`:

```
class FileInfo {
    private String name

    @JsonProperty("is_dir")
    private boolean isDirectory

    @JsonProperty("last_modified")
    private String lastModifiedTime
}
```

I configured `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in `@Configuration  @EnableWebMvc` class.

and when return a `FileInfo` in controller handler with `@ResponseBody`,THERE is no `name` in result json;

I know the pogo property is accessed by  `public void setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);`

So are there a annotation on class that can mark a pogo that can convert by jackson? cuz it is too noisy use `@JSONProperty` on every property.

Comment: add setter and getter can solve this ,but make pogo ugly.

Comment: Why not make name public (ie just remove `private` so you have `String name`)

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108530/1073826). The question shows how to set the visibility for a class and the accepted answer shows how to set the visibility for an entire ObjectMapper.

The idea is to set the field visibility to `Visibility.ANY` to pick up private fields.