# how i can post json to springboot controller with @Embedded in @Embeddable class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

the user entity

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer age;

@Embedded
private Address address;

public User(){}

public User(String name, Integer age,Address address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}

public User(String name, Integer age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

and the address entity

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Embeddable
public class Address {

private String city;

public Address() {
}

public Address( String city) {
    this.city = city;

}



public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}


}
```

the controller code

```
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void users(@RequestBody List<User> users) {
    this.userRepository.save(users);

}
```

when i post json data with psot man, the data is

```
[
 {
  "name":"yaohao",
  "age":11,
  "address":{
    "city":"nantong"
 }

  },
  {
  "name":"yh",
  "age":11,
   "address":{
    "city":"nantong"
  }

 }
]
```

[the address always null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYdyg.png)

when the user entity has no @Embedded address entity，the code works fine，so how can i post json data to controller when i use @Embedded  annotations

Comment: You don't have a getter and setter for `Address`.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the use of `@Embedded`. When doing the marshaling Jackson uses Java Bean properties to set the values and as your `User` class is lacking a `getAddress` and `setAddress` Jackson simply ignores it because it doesn't exists.

To fix add the getter and setter for `Address`.

Or instead of using **property** access switch your mapper to use **field** access. See [how to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally) for more information on that.