# How to use Jackson to conditionally serialise the fields of a POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a java class

```
    public class CategoryItem implements Serializable {
    private Long id;            

    private String name;           

    private Manager manager;
}
```

In one case,I need to convert all the fields to json.
on the other case,I only need 'id'and 'name' 
How can I do?

Give me some tips.Thanks

Comment: Have you research any thing?

Comment: set unwanted field null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your POJO `id` and `name` attributes with @JsonProperty and manager with @JsonIgnore

When you want just `id` and `name`, use a default ObjectMapper.
When you want all fields, use a custom ObjectMapper per this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

1. set unwanted field to `null`, and use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation at class level.
2. supply `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`, while using `ObjectMapper` and use annotation `@JsonFilter(<filter_name>)` at class level.
3. use a custom-serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `@JsonView` (kudos to [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#bd-4-jsonview)):

**`@JsonView` indicates the View in which the property will be included for serialization/deserialization.**

For example, we'll use @JsonView to serialize an instance of Item entity.

First, let's start with the views:

```java
public class Views {
    public static class Public {}
    public static class Internal extends Public {}
}
```

Next here's the Item entity using the views:

```java
public class Item {
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public int id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public String itemName;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public String ownerName;
}
```

Finally, the full test:

```java
@Test
public void whenSerializingUsingJsonView_thenCorrect()
  throws JsonProcessingException {
    Item item = new Item(2, "book", "John");

    String result = new ObjectMapper()
      .writerWithView(Views.Public.class)
      .writeValueAsString(item);

    assertThat(result, containsString("book"));
    assertThat(result, containsString("2"));
    assertThat(result, not(containsString("John")));
}
```