# Jackson UnrecognizedPropertyException thrown when it's there

Tags: java, jackson2, jackson-databind

I have a basic spring boot standalone executable jar using the bott 2.0.0.0  I think this is simple, but Google won't give up the answer.  :)  I am am using the latest stable jackson versions  (2.9.4) but they ARE being managed by spring.  This is a Boolean problem:

here is the JSON I am trying to turn into a Java Pojo  (it is wrapped in a higher object but I don't think that's the problem.  I haveing problems qith the boolean.

```
{
    "guid": "a5182918-8d69-11e6-acb6-0a97227b08ed",
    "organizationId": 1,
    "region": "Tariff Picker",
    "stages": [{
        "nextStages": [],
        "activities": [{
            "nextActivities": [],
            "name": "New Activity",
            "suspensionReason": "",
            "rules": [],
            "isSuspend": false,
            "sequence": 1,
            "allowedRoles": [{
                "userApplications": [],
                "name": "submitApplication",
                "organizationId": 0,
                "workQueues": [],
                "roleApplicationsForSystemRoleId": [],
                "isPublic": 0,
                "widgetRoles": [],
                "userRoles": [],
                "roleTariffReports": [],
                "roleTypeId": 0,
                "distributionListRoles": [],
                "organizationRoles": [],
                "publicationRoles": [],
                "roleTariffDataSets": [],
                "roleApplicationsForApplicationRoleId": [],
                "workQueueArchives": [],
                "id": 11,
                "rolePrivileges": []
            }],
            "label": "New Activity",
            "irrevocable": false,
            "stageId": 0,
            "id": 0,
            "buttonPrompt": "Submit",
            "guid": "2e195e0c-83d2-491f-b2e8-3ad1159d1d99",
            "dataBlock": {
                "sections": [{
                    "info": "",
                    "prompt": "",
                    "name": "First Section",
                    "sequence": 0,
                    "fields": [],
                    "gatingConditions": [],
                    "guid": "480d160c-c34f-4022-97b0-e8a1f28c49ae",
                    "id": -2
                }],
                "prompt": "",
                "id": -1,
                "name": ""
            },
            "autoExecute": false
        }],
        "name": "Tariff Selection Stage",
        "sequence": 1,
        "rules": [],
        "completionMessage": "",
        "guid": "65a73280-c587-486f-be8b-9107426f4730",
        "id": 0,
        "description": ""
    }],
    "stop": "3000-01-01",
    "workflowTypeId": 2,
    "isUserAction": false,
    "start": "1900-01-01",
    "isSandbox": false,
    "gatingConditions": [],
    "tariffId": 49,
    "businessCalendarId": 1,
    "applicationForms": [],
    "id": 49,
    "rules": []
}
```

I am getting an error saying there is not a field named "isSuspend" and as you can see it is there (line 3) and even set to false.  here is my pojo:

```
    private int id;
private String name;
private List<DataBlockObject> dataBlocks;
private int sequence;
private List<RuleObject> rules;
private List<AllowedRoleObject> allowedRoles;
private List<NextActivityObject> nextActivities;
private List<ActivityPermissionObject> activityPermissions;
private boolean autoExecute;
private boolean irrevocable;
private String label;
private String buttonPrompt;
private int stageId;
private boolean isSuspend;
private String suspensionReason;
private String guid;
private List<ActivitySubmitErrorPromptObject> activitySubmitErrorPrompts;
private int activitySubmitErrorTimeout;
private String breadcrumbClass;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public List<DataBlockObject> getDataBlocks() {
    return dataBlocks;
}
public void setDataBlocks(List<DataBlockObject> dataBlocks) {
    this.dataBlocks = dataBlocks;
}
public int getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}
public void setSequence(int sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
}
public List<RuleObject> getRules() {
    return rules;
}
public void setRules(List<RuleObject> rules) {
    this.rules = rules;
}
public List<AllowedRoleObject> getAllowedRoles() {
    return allowedRoles;
}
public void setAllowedRoles(List<AllowedRoleObject> allowedRoles) {
    this.allowedRoles = allowedRoles;
}
public List<NextActivityObject> getNextActivities() {
    return nextActivities;
}
public void setNextActivities(List<NextActivityObject> nextActivities) {
    this.nextActivities = nextActivities;
}
public List<ActivityPermissionObject> getActivityPermissions() {
    return activityPermissions;
}
public void setActivityPermissions(List<ActivityPermissionObject> activityPermissions) {
    this.activityPermissions = activityPermissions;
}
public boolean isAutoExecute() {
    return autoExecute;
}
public void setAutoExecute(boolean autoExecute) {
    this.autoExecute = autoExecute;
}
public boolean isIrrevocable() {
    return irrevocable;
}
public void setIrrevocable(boolean irrevocable) {
    this.irrevocable = irrevocable;
}
public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}
public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}
public String getButtonPrompt() {
    return buttonPrompt;
}
public void setButtonPrompt(String buttonPrompt) {
    this.buttonPrompt = buttonPrompt;
}
public int getStageId() {
    return stageId;
}
public void setStageId(int stageId) {
    this.stageId = stageId;
}
public boolean isSuspend() {
    return isSuspend;
}
public void setSuspend(boolean isSuspend) {
    this.isSuspend = isSuspend;
}
public String getSuspensionReason() {
    return suspensionReason;
}
public void setSuspensionReason(String suspensionReason) {
    this.suspensionReason = suspensionReason;
}
public String getGuid() {
    return guid;
}
public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
}
public List<ActivitySubmitErrorPromptObject> getActivitySubmitErrorPrompts() {
    return activitySubmitErrorPrompts;
}
public void setActivitySubmitErrorPrompts(List<ActivitySubmitErrorPromptObject> activitySubmitErrorPrompts) {
    this.activitySubmitErrorPrompts = activitySubmitErrorPrompts;
}
public int getActivitySubmitErrorTimeout() {
    return activitySubmitErrorTimeout;
}
public void setActivitySubmitErrorTimeout(int activitySubmitErrorTimeout) {
    this.activitySubmitErrorTimeout = activitySubmitErrorTimeout;
}
public String getBreadcrumbClass() {
    return breadcrumbClass;
}
public void setBreadcrumbClass(String breadcrumbClass) {
    this.breadcrumbClass = breadcrumbClass;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can the problem be because of the getter and setter names for the field isSuspend? Try naming getter and setter getIsSuspend and setIsSuspend

Answer (score 2):

Your POJO doesn't follow Java Beans naming convention. If you want Jackson to not look at the getters/setters, but only fields, see this: [how to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105745/839733)