# Jackson @JsonProperty create duplicate name

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Table(name = "Sheduler")
public @Data class Lesson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public int id;

    String state;
    String goal;
    String hobby;
    String result;
    String interest;

    @JsonProperty("fStudentRequest") 
    boolean fStudentRequest;
    @JsonProperty("fTeacherConfirm") 
    boolean fTeacherConfirm;
    @JsonProperty("fStudentConfirm") 
    boolean fStudentConfirm;

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    AuthorisedUser student; 

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    AuthorisedUser teacher; 

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    List<Robokassa> robokassa = new ArrayList<>();  

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
        mappedBy = "sheduler"
    )
    List<LessonDays> days = new ArrayList<>();  
}
```

To serialise result I use additional class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import lombok.Data;
import play.Logger;
public @Data class HttpJsonResponse<T> {


    int status;
    String message;
    List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int code;

    public static <T> String createUserResponse(T data,String message,int code,int status){
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
            HttpJsonResponse<T> response = new HttpJsonResponse<T>();
            response.setStatus(status);
            response.setCode(code);
            response.getData().add(data);
            response.setMessage(message);
            Logger.debug(mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            Logger.error(e.toString());
            return "{\"status\":0,\"data\":[],\"code\":\"901\",\"message\":\"error\"}";     
        }
    }
}
```

When I serialize Lesson class I get duplicated fields

```
String result = HttpJsonResponse
                .createUserResponse(
                    lessons,
                    "find "+lessons.size(),
                    CODE_OK,
                    STAUS_OK
                );
```

Sorry for this but I cannot add more code in my post

```
{
   "status":1,
   "message":"find 1",
   "data":[
      [
         {
            "id":4565,
            "state":"4",
            "goal":"4",
            "hobby":"hobby",
            "result":"result",
            "interest":"4",
            "student":{
               "id":0,
               "email":null,
               "password":null,
               "md5":"e22175516bc91b167e80ceae7276d83b",
               "hash":null,
               "tags":null,
               "emotions":null,
               "balance":0.0,
               "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

               }
            },
            "teacher":{
               "id":0,
               "email":null,
               "password":null,
               "md5":"e22175516bc91b167e80ceae7276d83b",
               "hash":null,
               "tags":null,
               "emotions":null,
               "balance":0.0,
               "hibernateLazyInitializer":{

               }
            },
            "robokassa":null,
            "days":[
               {
                  "id":4558,
                  "from":"10:00",
                  "to":"10:45",
                  "fselect":true,
                  "fSelect":true
               },
               {
                  "id":4559,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4560,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4561,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4562,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4563,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4564,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4566,
                  "from":"10:00",
                  "to":"11:00",
                  "fselect":true,
                  "fSelect":true
               },
               {
                  "id":4567,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4568,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4569,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4570,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4571,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               },
               {
                  "id":4572,
                  "from":null,
                  "to":null,
                  "fselect":false,
                  "fSelect":false
               }
            ],
            "fteacherConfirm":true,
            "fstudentConfirm":true,
            "fstudentRequest":true,
            "fStudentRequest":true,
            "fTeacherConfirm":true,
            "fStudentConfirm":true
         }
      ]
   ],
   "code":500
}
```

What should I do to remove duplicates and get field like fStudentConfirm

Comment: how do you serialize?(I understood you use Jackson but how?)

Comment: add serialize code

Comment: @AlexandrLukovnikov seems impossible to me. It's not that I don't trust you, it's that I've never seen something like that happen. Which version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: @AlexandrLukovnikov Just tested, result is perfectly valid. Are you sure you didn't get confused?

Comment: Well it seemed imposible to me too. So i tried it. Result:  all values only one time as it should be. Something relevant missing in your post? Also your posted output doesn't look like a Jackson output(no Quotes, no braces, no comma).

Comment: I edit my post. Add additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These field names are not equal. There is a difference: `f`**t**`eacherConfirm` and `f`**T**`eacherConfirm`. Probably, you are using `Lambok` which generates for you getters and setters. In this specific scenario where field names has one strange letter `f` `Lambok` probably creates `is-method` like below:

```
public boolean isFstudentRequest() {
    return fStudentRequest;
}
```

Now, `Jackson` sees that you have annotation over property and other `is-method` which has other name it generate two similar (not equal) properties in `JSON`.

Solutions:

1. Remove that `f` at the beginning or add whole word which starts from `f`.
2. Remove `Lambok` and generate `is-method` manually where you have total control on the generated name.
3. Disable `is-methods` in `Jackson` like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
```

See also:

1. [how to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue in Spring boot
what i did was added @JsonProperty to each getters and setters. It might be a workaround. I tried playing with spring "spring.jackson.mapper" but it didn't help.

```
private String Name;
@JsonProperty("Name")
public Name getName() {
    return Name;
}
@JsonProperty("Name")
public void setName(Name name) {
    Name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the property name generated by lombok getter:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value={"fstudentRequest", "fstudentConfirm"})
@Table(name = "Sheduler")
public @Data class Lesson {
    // ...
}
```