# Jackson not serializing property

Tags: java, json, jackson2

I have the following two enums

```
public enum Action {
    ACTION1,
    ACTION2,
    ACTION3;
}
```

```
public enum EntityType {
    ENTITYTYPE1,
    ENTITYTYPE2;
}
```

and the following class

```
public class EntityIdentityDto implements MetaData {
    private String id;
    private EntityType entityType;
    private Action action;
    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap();

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public EntityType getEntityType() {
        return this.entityType;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return this.action;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return this.properties;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setEntityType(EntityType entityType) {
          this.entityType = entityType;
    }

    public void setAction(Action action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public EntityIdentityDto() {
    }

}
```

When using Jackson 2.9.8 to serialize into Json as per below

```
public class TestMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        EntityIdentityDto entityIdentityDto = new EntityIdentityDto();
        entityIdentityDto.setEntityType(EntityType.ENTITYTYPE1);
        entityIdentityDto.setAction(Action.ACTION1);
        entityIdentityDto.setId("OOO");
        String out = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entityIdentityDto);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
{"id":"OOO","action":"ACTION1","properties":{}}
```

I am expecting to so the entityType field serialized as well but this is missing. This is what I expect to see

```
{"id":"OOO","entityType": "ENTITYTYPE1", "action":"ACTION1","properties":{}}
```

If instead of Jackson I use Gson as per below

```
public class TestMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        EntityIdentityDto entityIdentityDto = new EntityIdentityDto();
        entityIdentityDto.setEntityType(EntityType.SYSTEM);
        entityIdentityDto.setAction(Action.SYNC);
        entityIdentityDto.setId("OOO");
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(entityIdentityDto));
    }
}
```

The output is as expected

```
{"id":"OOO","entityType":"ENTITYTYPE1","action":"ACTION1","properties":{}}
```

Why is the entityType field missing in the Json generated using Jackson ? 
It is interesting that action gets serialized but entityType does not even though they are structurally identical and used identically in the EntityIdentityDto

Comment: For me, Jackson also produced the same output. Which version of Jackson are you using? I tried it on version `2.10.0.pr3`. Probably you are missing getters?

Comment: I would guess this is an environment/configuration/forgot-to-recompile-all-classes type error

Comment: I would guess this is also environment/configuration/forgot-to-recompile-all-classes type issue but can confirm I have cleaned the environment, rebuilt using both the IDE and gradle with the same result.

Comment: @KhethoMtembo, how `ObjectMapper` configuration looks like? Do you use any modules, custom serialisers, filters, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my EntityIdentityDto class which implements the following interface

```
public interface MetaData {
    String getId();
    Map<String, Object> getProperties();
    void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties);

    @JsonIgnore
    EntityType getEntityType();
}
```

The JsonIgnore at the interface level is the reason why it was not being serialized. After dropping the JsonIgnore all works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you do not have getter for `entityType` property. Add getter or use [setVisibility](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setVisibility-com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor-com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility-) method:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

See also:

1. [how to specify jackson to only use fields - preferably globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally)
2. [Jackson – Decide What Fields Get Serialized/Deserialized](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not)
3. [Exclude Fields from Serialization in Gson](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization)

Comment: I use lombok to generate the getters and setters. I have updated the question to show the generated code used at runtime.

Comment: @KhethoMtembo, How it works with `setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)`? The output is the same?

Comment: The entityType field still does not get serialized with visibility set to ANY

Comment: Did you added the `Serializable` interface for your entity class?

Comment: @megloff, no, it is not required.