# Jackson force serialization of final fields without annotations

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class with a private constructor that I cannot modify containing many final fields that I wish to serialize with Jackson. Is there any way to force Jackson to serialize all the final fields?

I've tried using a custom filter provider like so: `new ObjectMapper().setFilterProvider(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("serialize-final", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll()))` but Jackson seems to filter out the final fields before/after it applies my filter.

The use case is my program depends on a library that uses feature flags to indicate which features are enabled. The distributor of the library has compiled the feature flags into final fields on a singleton object that I am able to access at runtime. I wish to add the ability to dump the feature flags when requested to allow for easier debugging and simply serializing them as JSON seems like the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the singleton does not have getters for the final fields (else it works out of the box). You could use the field visibility checker as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally):

```
    public class SerializeFinalFields {

        @Test
        public void doTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
            final TestClass t = new TestClass("flag");
            final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            // Older jackson versions:
            // om.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
            // om.setVisibility(
            //      om.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            //              .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));
            // newer jackson versions:
            om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

            final String json = om.writeValueAsString(t);
            System.out.println(json);
        }

    }

    class TestClass {

        private final String myField;

        /* package */ TestClass(final String myField) {
            this.myField = myField;
        }
    }
```